# Find Title Attribute & Link Title in HTML using REGEX

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver

I used `<a[^>]*?title=\"([^\"]*?\"[^>]*?>` and found all Links with title tags. How can I find all Links with no title tags & title attribute? And how can I find all image ALT tags that are empty or have no ALT tag?

Comment: What happens if I define the title with the use of an SGML parsed entity? Huh? Huh? (HTML is far nastier than it appears to be at first glance, as Fredrik points out. **Use a proper parser.** We mean it.)

Answer (score 2):

See this classic post on SO [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: <img\s+((width|height|border|class|id|src|usemap|hspace|vspace)="[^"]+"\s*)+/?>  This works for finding images with no alt tags.

Comment: <a\s+((class|id|href|)="[^"]+"\s*)+/?>  finds with no titles

Comment: Yikes! and what if the structure changes or goes multiline? Go for a html-parser before you hurt yourself

Answer (score 2):

@Fredrik has you covered pretty well, I think, but here's an alternate general method for this kind of sophisticated find/replace in markup.

Since I'm no regex guru, I like to use **jQuery + browser debugger tools + copy/pasting** for this kind of thing.  I view the page in Firefox(Chrome/dev tools works great, too), open up the Firebug console, and perform the actions in jQuery goodies, something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if ($(this).filter('[title]').length == 0) {
    //if there's no title attr
  } else if ($(this).attr('title') == "") {
    //if title is empty empty
  } 
  // etc.
});

// repeat pattern for imgs...
```

When you're done with your manipulations, copy the relevant section from the debugger (or just grab the whole `<body>`) and paste it back into your editor.

I find this method much easier to understand than regexes, but that's just because I'm not too bright.  HTH.